# Python multiprocessing progress record

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress

I'm running a pythong program using the multiprocessing module to take advantage of multiple cores on the cpu.

The program itself works fine, but when it comes to show a kind of progress percentage it all messes up.

In order to try to simulate what happens to me, I've written this little scenario where I've used some random times to try to replicate some tasks that could take different times in the original program.

When you ran it, you'll see how percentages are mixed up.

Is there a propper way to achieve this?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import random
import time


def PrintPercent(percent):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    print(' (%s %%) Ready' %(percent))

def HeavyProcess(cont):
    total = 20
    cont[0] = cont[0] + 1
    percent = round((float(cont[0])/float(total))*100, 1)
    PrintPercent(percent)

def Main():

    cont = Manager().list(range(1))

    cont[0] = 0 
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(HeavyProcess, [cont])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

Main()
```

Comment: Maybe a `sys.stdout.flush()` would help after `print`.

Comment: @CristiFati The actual problem is that it seems like it doesn't "update" the variable data fast enough